# Does MS Teams have a url to install an application in Teams similar to what Slack has?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

While developing apps for Slack, we can distribute the app to other organizations using a url - https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize with appropriate scopes needed. We are able to add this url reference to a button and let users install the app by logging in to Slack.

Is there a similar url for MS Teams that can be used to install / distribute the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deep link for that:

> #### Deep linking to an app
>
> Create a deep link for the app after the app is listed in the Teams store. To create a link to launch Teams, append the app ID to the following URL: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/<your-app-id>`. A dialog box appears to install the app.
>
> *source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v1#deep-linking-to-an-app*

When user clicks on it, they will go to Teams and an app installation dialog will be shown for them to decide if they want to install the app.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does the deep link need the user to login to Teams on the webapp? Can you use a redirect url from the deep link to store which users have added the application?

Comment: Deep links are a navigation mechanism that you can use to connect users with information and features within Teams and Teams apps. So you need either Teams web login or Teams desktop login.
We cannot use a redirect url from the deep link to store which users have added the application.